# How to transfer parameter on DateTimePicker in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I have a list of bookings. I want to change the date and time of every items by using DateTimePicker. So I want to transfer the parameter "index". Those date list comes from DB.

[image]

Following is my code.

```
class Home extends Component {
  handleDatePicker = (date) => {
    console.log(date);   // =>  2020-12-31T08:54:57.132Z
  }

  renderBookings = ({ item, index }) => {
    <View>
      <Text>Date will be here such as Dec 23, 2020</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({ isDateVisible: true })}>
        <Image source={calendar} style={{ width: wp, height: wp }} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <DateTimePicker
        isVisible={this.state.isDateVisible}
        mode="date"
        onConfirm={this.handleDatePicker}     // How to transfer "index" parameter to handleDatePicker function
        onCancel={this.hideDatePicker}
      />
    </View>
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <FlatList
          data={BookingList}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
          renderItem={this.renderBookings}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure if what you doing is the correct approach but a code like this should do the job for you

```
handleDatePicker = (date,index) => {
console.log(index);
console.log(date);   // =>  2020-12-31T08:54:57.132Z
}
```

and then when you call the function

```
<DateTimePicker
    isVisible={this.state.isDateVisible}
    mode="date"
    onConfirm={(date) => this.handleDatePicker(date,index)}  
    onCancel={this.hideDatePicker}
  />
```

Comment: Thank you. It's working well. And Happy New Year.